# com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found on PySpark script on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm trying to create an EMR cluster using AWS CLI to run a python script (uses pyspark) as follows:

```
aws emr create-cluster --name "emr cluster for pyspark (test)"\
 --applications Name=Spark Name=Hadoop --release-label emr-5.25.0 --use-default-roles \
 --ec2-attributes KeyName=my-key --instance-groups \
 InstanceGroupType=MASTER,InstanceCount=1,InstanceType=m4.xlarge \
 InstanceGroupType=CORE,InstanceCount=2,InstanceType=m4.xlarge \
 --bootstrap-actions Path="s3://mybucket/my_bootstrap.sh" --steps \
 Type=CUSTOM_JAR,Name="Spark Count group by QRACE",ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE\
 ,Jar=s3://us-east-2.elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar,\
 Args=["s3://mybucket/my_step.py","s3://mybucket/my_input.txt","s3://mybucket/output"]\
 --log-uri "s3://mybucket/logs"
```

The bootstrap script sets up Python3.7, installs pyspark (2.4.3) and installs Java 8. However, my script fails with the following error:

```
y4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o32.csv.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.EmrFileSystem not found
```

I've tried adding a `--configurations` argument with the following json file to the `create-cluster` command (but it did not help):

```
[
{
  "Classification":"spark-defaults",
  "Properties":{
    "spark.executor.extraClassPath":"/etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*",
    "spark.driver.extraClassPath":"/etc/hadoop/conf:/etc/hive/conf:/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/aws-java-sdk/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/*:/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/auxlib/*"
  }
}
```

]

Any pointers as to where I could look or what I could do would be very helpful!

EDIT: I was able to fix this issue by following the suggestions of @Lamanus. But my PySpark application seems to run perfectly on EMR 5.30.1 but not on EMR 5.25.0

I am now getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1596402225924_0001 finished with failed status
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1148)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1525)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:849)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

I'm not sure where to look for a helpful error report /log for what went wrong. It works perfectly with EMR-5.30.1 and Spark-2.4.5.

Comment: EMR already has the pyspark, why do you need to reinstall?

Comment: I wanted to use a different version. Is there a way to do that without manually installing the version I want?

Comment: The version of spark in the image emr 5.25.0 is 2.4.3 and so the pyspark has the same, I think.

Comment: DON'T install pyspark. It overwrites all settings. I also tried the same with anaconda.
But FYI EMRFS jar is in `/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/lib/` directory named `emrfs-hadoop-assembly-<version>.jar`.

Comment: @Lamanus Thanks! That solved the original problem I was having but I've run into a new one now. Any ideas on where I might look?

Comment: @Snigdhajyoti Thanks! Do you have any idea as to what might be causing the new problem (i've edited original post)?

Comment: If are saving logs to S3 you will find log from EMR console. `application_1596402225924_0001` this is ur spark application ID. Or else SSH into master node and put this command `yarn logs -applicationId application_1596402225924_0001` or u can logs on spark UI.

Comment: Please provide logs. Without that it's hard to tell whats the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: this happened because bootstrap script installed pyspark  when the cluster already came with one.

Comment: I had the same error because one libreary installed with pip was installing pyspark as dependency

Answer (score 0):

Was not able to vote on the last answer by @chittychitty, but this is correct! Do not install PySpark over the one provided by EMR.